# How do I compare numbers and strings in racket

Tags: racket

If i wanted my string that I entered to be less than a certain number for example 10. If it is less than 10 i would assign it the value 25. How would I go about doing so?

```
(define (name n)
  (cond
    [(< (string-length nom) 10) 25]))
```

`n not defined`

Comment: Welcome to SO! this is not a place where you can simply dump your homework. Please share your efforts!

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for `set!` (for "assignment") in conjunction with `when` (for the condition).

```
#lang racket


(define (name i)
  (when (<= (string-length i) 10)
    (set! i 10))
  (displayln i))


(name "sustainability")
; => sustainability

(name "diversity")
; => 10
```